# unable to refresh data in excel from sharepoint

Tags: excel, data

I am using SharePoint 2010 and excel from office 2016. When i give export to excel from the SharePoint site, it works fine and loads the data in excel first time. But when i try refresh the data, it shows error as below.
"a connection to SharePoint site cannot be established. to synchronize or refresh your table, you much be able to connect to the SharePoint site."

Can anyone please help. All the service site settings are done and permissions are also set.

Answer (score 3):

Please go to excel > data > connections > connections to see if there is your connection (its name should be same with your file name) in this windows. If yes, please double click it and select definition tab to see if the detail information are correct.

If these things are ok, check your excel logged in user and site logged in user both are same or not.